# How to change my web app to use signature v4 for calling API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've been developing a web app with AWS for a few months now. I'm trying my best to make use of the best practices as much as possible. Going serverless, using API Gateway and Lambda functions, etc. At this point, I have a working web SPA making calls to API Gateway and now I came across the authentication/authorization for my APIs.

Learning about Cognito, I came across [this nice presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZqG7HjT2AQ) on different ways to utilize it for both authentication/authorization. My question is mostly in regard to authorization part. Apparently, there are three ways to implement authorization. And most secure one is signature v4. Putting aside the preparations I need to do on AWS to make this happen, I would like to know what are the changes that I need to apply to my client-side code.

Right now, the current implementation simply sends HTTP requests to the API Gateway with `id_token` embedded in the header. This makes sure that only authenticated users can make the call. But it does not check for authorization.

According to the presentation, if I want to use the signature v4, I have to exchange my `id_token` with some AWS Credentials (by making a call to Amazon Cognito Federated Identities) and then use those AWS Credentials to make a different version of my API Gateway request and use that instead.

Now, my questions are:

1. Do I need to make the call to Federated Identities explicitly?
2. If yes, does that mean that I have to make such calls each time I want to send a new request?
3. Any hints/examples on the implementation?

Comment: What is business domain of the web application? Whats your future plans of the API apart from the web app?

Comment: @Ashan I'm not sure what you mean, but at this point, the web app is all I'm working on. And please don't tell me again that I should look into Amplify. As good as it is, it's too late for this project of mine. Maybe next time I'll start my project with that :)

Comment: I asked the domain to see whether you need Signature4 and Federated Identities. You can use only UserPools for your API validating the id token with Cognito Authorizer depending on the level of AWS services access.

Comment: That's great, but correct me if I'm wrong, that's only authentication. And it does not provide me with authorization, right?

Comment: Yes its authentication. You can implement authorization either using Custom Authorizer or IAM authorizer with Federated Identities. If you go with the first option you can return a generated API Gateway policy to authorize the endpoints. With federated identities you can define them in IAM. I prefer the first option since it keeps client authentication limited to oauth or open id connect auth flow. For second option you also need to do an additional API call requiring AWS specific Signature4 signing process addition to authentication.

Comment: Thanks, it's always good to make sure that I'm on the right track. The business domain that I'm working on security is very important and I'm afraid that the project owner will ask for the maximum level which in this case it would be using signature-v4. Like you, I prefer using custom authorizers too. But here I'm just trying to understand the cost of going all the way.

Comment: As the name suggests AWS IAM authorizer is mainly there if your API grants AWS service specific actions. Thats why AWS signature4 is also needed with Federated identities. Even for maximum security OpenID connect flow is sufficient if you expose a REST API with business capabilities, rather AWS resources access.

Comment: I might end up using custom authorizer if I can convince others it's secure enough. But still it would be nice to know how to work with signature v4.

Comment: With Signature4 you need to do an additional API call passing the id_token. If you use AWS SDK signing process happens internally. Otherwise you need to implement that using couple of libraries. Then use API gateway policies and Userpool attributes to authorize endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, you can set up [API Gateway Authorization(Access Control) with IAM](http://link.medium.com/X6GaTwUjWX) through AWS console or AWS SAM API Auth Object. 
If you use SAM, it is as following:

```
MyApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    StageName: Prod
    Auth:
      DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
MyFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    FunctionName: MyFunction
    ...
    Events:
      Post:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /compute
          Method: POST
          RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
          Auth:
            Authorizer: AWS_IAM
```

On front-end, you can [use AWS Amplify sdk to access your API](https://link.medium.com/unR6Ok5y5X). It automatically signs your API requests with Signature V4.